# Button not showing up in a kivy application

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy.

The buttons and label in class P are not being displayed.

My python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
# from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def show_popup(self):
        popupWindow.popupdisplay.open()
    def close_popup(self):
        popupWindow.popupdisplay.dismiss()

class P(FloatLayout):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass
 
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("ty.kv")
class TyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

class popupWindow():
    show = P()
    popupdisplay = Popup(title="Incorrect Screen", content=show, size_hint=(None,None), size=(400,400))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TyApp().run()
```

The kivy file:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
<P>:
    Label:
        text: "Wrong input"
        size_hint: 0.6,0.2
        color:[1,1,1,1]
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "Close"
        size_hint: 0.8,0.2
        color:[1,1,1,1]
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "y":0.3}
        # on_release:
            # root.close_popup()

<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text:'Password: '
            TextInput:
                id: passw
                hint_text: 'Enter your password'
                multiline: False
        Button:
            id:bt1
            text: "Sumbit"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "second" if passw.text == 'test' else root.show_popup()
                root.manager.transition.direction= 'left'

<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    Button:
        text:"Go back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction= 'right'
```

I am talking about the following label and button:

```
<P>:
    Label:
        text: "Wrong input"
        size_hint: 0.6,0.2
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "Close"
        size_hint: 0.8,0.2
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "y":0.3}
        # on_release:
            # root.close_popup()
```

What I have tried so far: Initally, the popupwindow class was a function and it worked fine by creating a 'btn' button and calling it when the password didn't match the condition. However, I created a class and readjusted things because I couldn't find a way to close the popup. So, when the condition is unsatisfied the button and the label is not being displayed and the following pop is shown:

[image]

It would be appreciated if you could help me figure out the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the `open()` method of the `Popup` in order for it to display itself. Try the following slight change:

```
class popupWindow():
    show = P()
    popupdisplay = Popup(title="Incorrect Screen", content=show, size_hint=(None,None), size=(400,400))
    popupdisplay.open()
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this and it does not work. Moreover, I have already called the popup method through show_popup function in mainWindow class.